# Can sums of squares in a field always be written as the sum of four squares?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field. Let $S$ be the set of elements of $\mathbb{F}$ that can be written as a sum of squares. For $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Q},$ four squares might be required. Is there any field such that $S$ contains elements that aren't the sum of four squares? What is the smallest $n$ such that it is guaranteed that all elements of $S$ are the sum of $n$ squares?

Comment: Is the [tag:sums-of-squares] tag applicable here?

Comment: The technical term for what you're asking about is the Pythagoras number of a field ("is it always at most $4$"?). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoras_number.

Comment: The tag sum-of-squares is related to expressing integers as sums of squares (based on tag description). It is not required for the current question which deals with elements of a general field.

Comment: @KCd Thanks. A good answer would provide an easy-to-understand explanation of the statement that "Every positive integer occurs as the Pythagoras number of some formally real field."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a field $F$, the minimal number $n$ such that every sum of squares in a $F$ is a sum of at most $n$ squares is called the Pythagoras number of $F$.

The discussion on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229515/pythagorean-number-in-artins-theorem-on-nonnegative-rational-fractions) indicates that the calculation of the Pythagoras number for the rational function field $\mathbf R(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ is still largely open.  It is known to be in the interval $[m+1,2^m]$, so for $m = 1$ the value is $2$. For $m = 2$, it is a theorem of Cassels, Ellison, and Pfister that the value is $4$. For $m \geq 3$ the exact value has not been determined.

Hoffmann, in 1998 [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1999-12-03/S0894-0347-99-00301-X/S0894-0347-99-00301-X.pdf), showed every positive integer is the Pythagoras number of some formally real field (that means a field that is an ordered field in at least one way, or equivalently $-1$ is not a sum of squares in the field).